# Is it ok to pass function's call as arguments to functions in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, constructor

So basically, is it ok to call fun() as an argument like `ethToWeiConverter` in the example below? Otherwise, what style is preferable?

```
contract RefundableCrowdsale {
  uint256 cap;

  RefundableCrowdsale (uint256 _cap) {
    cap = _cap;
  }
}


contract MyCrowdsale is RefundableCrowdsale {

  // constructor
  function MyCrowdsale (cap) RefundableCrowdsale (
    ethToWeiConverter(cap)
  ) {
    ...
  }

  function ethToWeiConverter(uint256 eths) returns (uint256) {
    return eths * 10**18
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like your not passing a function as an argument in your example above, but calling another function. I think it's ok to do. But your example above is sort of incomplete.

Comment: Thanks @EduardoPereira for pointing out. I've edited question description to be more correct

Comment: the syntax that you include in your code block above is not supported by Solidity, and I am not sure I understand what you are asking or trying to do. In any case, Solidity is not a functional programming language - functions are not objects, they cannot be passed as arguments to functions as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to pass functions as parameters. [From a comment on ethdev by Chriseth](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/6zn4a1/how_to_write_clean_elegant_solidity_code_using/dmx90an/)

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;

contract B {

    function plus(uint a, uint b) internal returns (uint) {
        return a + b;
    }

    function minus(uint a, uint b) internal returns (uint) {
        return a - b;
    }

    function eval(function (uint, uint) internal returns (uint) f, uint x, uint y) internal returns (uint) {
        return f(x, y);
    }

    function calc(uint op, uint x, uint y) constant public returns (uint) {
        function (uint, uint) internal returns (uint) g;
        if (op == 0) {
            g = plus;
        } else if (op == 1) {
            g = minus;
        }
        return eval(g, x, y);
    }
}
```

Note: This doesn't compile in remix, the parser get confused.